# what is Siri consuming? is Wifi enough? or 3g celluar data is involved while Siri searches online?

Tags: wifi, siri

So I am concerned if I can save data usage(I have only 200M per month on my account..) by using Siri at home(with a wifi connection)??

Comment: Totally offtopic for this site, but this should be of some use: http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2011/11/how-data-heavy-is-siri-on-an-iphone-4s-ars-investigates.ars

Answer (score 2):

You will save on data usage if you only use Siri at home with a wifi connection. Siri sends the raw audio of your talking to its servers, so the data usage will be comparable to using VoIP. Although that's only if you talk constantly to Siri (which I'm actually seeing some people at work doing these days).